# ifAlias set but not showing from snmp query

Tags: linux, networking, centos, snmp

I'm in a dead end with this problem.
I set an ifAlias for some interfaces for some testing, the alias seems set properly:

```
$ ip link show
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    alias test

$ cat /sys/devices/pcixxx/xxxx/virtio0/net/eth0/ifalias
test
```

However, when trying to query the ifAlias with SNMP I get nothing in return:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -On -c community 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.2 = STRING:
```

The system is running CentOs 7.9.
Am I missing something? Do I need to set the ifAlias differently?
I'll be grateful for any suggestion on the matter.